# Dynamic height and view more capability for objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextview

I am trying to display facebook feed from a json object on a uitable view. I am using a uitextview for displaying the text. How can i add the *view more/Continue Reading* capability which is common on the facebook app for larger text as shown in the picture below
[image]

Comment: You could measure the size of the text and if it is too large to fit you could show the "Continue Reading" button in the bottom right.

Comment: And after pressing continue reading how to modify the heightForRowAtIndexPath method @Dominic

Comment: There are some good examples of this on the internet. Have a look and raise a new question if you still have a problem. Happy coding! :)

Comment: @Dominic the answers are all for uitableviewcell i am making my own custom tableviewcell i tried using notification center but failed

Answer (score 0):

Check out 
 `- boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:` [(reference)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:) as a way to get the size of the text you want to display. If the bounding rect is larger than the amount of space you have available you'll know you need to display your 'continue reading' button.  Tapping the button could cause the cell to redraw with a larger height, based on the size of the bounding rect you calculated.